# angular select option ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have trouble making a select working with ng-repeat on option.

The problem is my code work well on plunkr but NOT in my project.
The field is not pre selected in the list :

[image]
so we can see that the variable is not null ( contain "subf." )

the plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/OMDKOeAFE8aCoX6fB6Vx?p=preview

html code :

```
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="rrtestListeTmp"> Repeat select:{{testListeTmp.value}} </label>
                <select id="rrtestListeTmp" name="rrtestListeTmp" ng-model="testListeTmp.value">
                    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in testListeTmp.liste" value="{{key}}">
                        {{value}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

JS :

```
        $scope.testListeTmp = {
            'value': "subf.",
            'liste': {
                "subsp.": "subspecies",
                "var.": "varietas",
                "subvar.": "subvarietas",
                "f.": "forma",
                "subf.": "subforma"
            }
        };
```

Comment: use ng-selected for preselected value, until your specific issue is not resolved...

Comment: if i use your solution the selected field is ok but when i change the select my self it keep first  one .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `ng-init` in the `<select>` to initialize the model's value?

Comment: the model is binded to a variable from the controller who is already initialised

Answer (score 0):

this syntax finally work

```
<select class="form-control input-md" 
        ng-model="testListeTmp.value"
        ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in testListeTmp.liste">
</select>
```